# Criteria you should mention in your question, for each type of software

Tags: discussion, question-quality, questions

We sometimes get questions like "What criteria should I consider for X" (which are [off-topic](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98/are-what-are-criteria-for-x-on-topic)).
Also, we often get questions with not enough criteria (even though they comply with [the general rule](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)) because askers are newcomers to the field and are not too sure what criteria they should look for.

As we gather experience on this, I think we should maintain a list of criteria for each general type of software. It might be too hard or too ambitious, but let's try.

Answer (score 8):

Guidelines for ALL questions: [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

---

## Desktop software

- Is a graphical interface (GUI) mandatory, or are command-line (CLI) solutions also acceptable?
- Is it acceptable if (minor) programming skills are required to "fully adjust" a product to your other requirements?

### Optical Character Recognition (OCR) software

- What language do you want to recognize? An OCR good with English might not be good with Japanese.

### Synchronization/backup software

- Are you OK with your data being stored on third-party servers? Do you have your own server? Is it enough to have peer-to-peer connections between your machines?

---

## Enterprise software

- Do you need professional/community support, with what budget per year?
- How many users does the software need to support?

### Business Intelligence

- Do you need [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load), ROLAP/[OLAP cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube)?
- Do you need need static reports (for instance PDF files), or dynamic reporting with drill-down, or semi-dynamic reporting with dashbaords and filtering?
- Who will design new reports? BI specialists, programmers, system administrators, people with some computer knowledge, people with no computer knowledge?

### Database interface

- What database are you using? Is it compatible with SQL?

### Document management/ECM software

- Usage

  - How do you want to access the system? Via [CIFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIFS), [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services), Web?
  - If you need a Web UI, do you need commenting/liking documents, instant preview without downloading, Single-Sign-On with an existing user database?
  - Do you need document versionning, ACLs, workflows, full-text search?
- Content

  - What kind of documents do you want to manage? Physical dead-tree paper, scanned papers, files generated by an office suite like Microsoft Office, other? Are you a media company handling mostly videos or images? Are you an engineering company handling mostly CAD files generated by professional design software?
  - Are you OK with information being stored on a third-party cloud server?
- Integration

  - Do you need to integrate with any hardware, for instance scanners, bar-code readers, tape storage?
  - Do you need to integrate with any software, for instance [ERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_resource_planning), [PLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_lifecycle_management), [CRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_relationship_management)?

### Enterprise Service Bus

- What systems do you want to integrate? (list them all)
- What protocols do you need? (list them all)
- Do you need a graphical user interface for configuration?
- Do you want to be able to customize code? If yes, any preference for the language (Java etc)?

---

## Mobile applications

- Should it be usable offline?

### GPS/navigation apps

- In what language do you want the map labels to show?

### Device specific apps

- Should it be able to run on non-jailbroken/non-rooted devices?

---

## Webapps

- Should it have an export feature so that you can get your data out of the service?

---

## Libraries (*programming*)

- In what programming language are you writing the code that will call the library?
- Should it be freely redistributable? Or are you OK with paying royalties for embedding the library into your software?

### Mock libraries

- Should it generate mocks dynamically?

Comment: "Libraries > What programming language?" -> maybe specify language of the API or language the library itself.